# Rails newbie, been struggling to solve this syntax error for the past few hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I believe the problem lies in the controller code.

I'm getting the following error:

```
"app/controllers/places_controller.rb:74: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input"
```

Before, everything was working fine. I ran a migration to have it work with the paperclip gem. I have been following the instructions on the github page. I also updated the models (I commented out the code for the models but still was getting the same error). This leads me to believe, the issue lies in the controller itself.

The funny thing is, the controller was working fine before with the same code, but now it's not. I have attached the full controller code below.

```
pclass PlacesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /places
# GET /places.json
def index
@places = Place.all
end

# GET /places/1
# GET /places/1.json
def show
end

# GET /places/new
def new
@place = Place.new
end

# GET /places/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /places
# POST /places.json
def create
@place = Place.new(place_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @place.save
    format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @place }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /places/1
# PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @place.update(place_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @place }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

# DELETE /places/1
# DELETE /places/1.json
def destroy
@place.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to places_url, notice: 'Place was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_place
  @place = Place.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def place_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:name, :description, :rating, :images)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first line is:

```
pclass PlacesController < ApplicationController
```

it should be:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: YOU ARE A HERO!!! I have literally been struggling with this for the past few hours. Now I feel kind of dumb for missing something so obvious haha ...

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to add `hero` to my resume now ;)  Please accept my answer if you're all set.